# Sitecore Emailcampaign:Delete user from Engagement plan of triggered message

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-ecm

I want to trigger an email to user on password reset by calling triggered message in code.
If user doesn't reset the password, then we need to schedule another email, engagement plan is set for this.

**Issue am facing**

Engagement plan is allowing user to enroll only once. If the user resets the password again then user is not moving to the first state.

Is there any way to move the user to first state of engagement plan if user resets the password again.

Thanks,

Rajesh kumar

Answer (score 2):

There's 2 options for you OOTB:

Either you can add an action for when they get to the last stage in your plan:

```
Remove Visitor from this Plan
```

That will remove the visitor from the plan altogether.

Alternatively you could add a trigger to the state they're in (check once per day for instance), and if they've triggered the password reset again use the action

```
Move Visitor to Another State
```

Moving them to the first state in the plan.

Comment: Do I want to add an action at the last state to remove user from this plan. If so how to do that, Any links/help is highly appreciated

Comment: Well, you can add an Action to the 'Yes' branch of a condition. So in the Design mode, when the user goes into the last state you can add the action 'Remove Visitor from this Plan' there.